# Does the Dell Equallogic PS5000E accept SSD drives?

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, ssd, dell-equallogic

I have an EQL PS5000E which with a recently expired support contract.  I am running firmware 6.0.2 and given that this is an old array I don't plan to renew support.  My VAR says that the PS5000E can be loaded with either 8 SSD to run it in tiered mode or fully loaded with 16 SSDs.

Supposedly the PS5000E has been opened up to non-Dell disks since fw 6.x and the controller will state "foreign disk" but will allow non-Dell disks to work.

I checked the firmware release notes and couldn't find any info about the PS5000E being able to work with SSD either in tiered or full configuration.  Does anyone have first hand knowledge of the PS5000E running with SSDs?

Comment: And even if you do, you'll kill your SSDs quite fast on that Dell EQL.

Comment: @DanilaLadner it would just be for a lab environment that only gets used once a week for 3 hours, so wearing them out wouldn't be too much of a concern, alas based on the link Chopper3 provided it just won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - only the PS6xxx series - see [HERE](http://www.expresscomputersystems.com/dell-ps5000e-12tb-capacity-two-controllers-pr-20630.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful with the graphical display of the controller colors.